# Dynamic select menus in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have been reading numerous articles about this and even watched the Railscast but nothing seems to fit my situation.

How can I update the "height" select options with the results of my Ajax request?

```
<%= nested_form_for @estimate do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :date %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :date %><br />
  <%= f.label :job_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :job_name %><br />

  <%= f.fields_for :items do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :description %><br />
    <%= builder.text_field :description %><br />
    <%= builder.label :material %><br />
    <%= builder.select :material, @letters.map { |l| [l.material, l.material] }, {}, :id => "material_field" %><br />
    <%= builder.label :height %><br />
    <%= builder.select :height, @letters.map { |l| [l.height, l.height] }, {}, :id => "height_field" %><br />
    <%= builder.label :thickness %><br />
    <%= builder.select :thickness, @letters.map { |l| [l.thickness, l.thickness] }, {}, :id => "thickness_field" %><br />

    <%= builder.label :quantity %><br />
    <%= builder.text_field :quantity, :id => "quantity_field" %>
    <%= builder.link_to_remove "Remove this item" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.link_to_add "Add a item", :items %>
  <%= f.submit "Add item" %>


<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#material_field").change(function() {
    //alert("hello")
    var material = $("#material_field").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/estimates/height_options?material=' + material, type: 'get', dataType: 'html',
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        //Not sure what to do here with the returned data
      }
    });    
});

</script>


class EstimatesController < ApplicationController

  def height_options
    @heights = Letter.find_all_by_material(params[:material])
    if @heights.blank?
      render :text => "Record not found"
    else
      render :json => @heights
    end
  end

end
```

The Ajax request is working properly and it is returning an array of the appropriate Letters.  Where do I go from here?  I will really appreciate anyone's help with this.

Answer (score 1):

In your generated html code you have something like that :

```
<select id="item_height">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
</select>
```

You can insert other option markups into your select via a jQuery method. I think that something like that can work :

```
$("#item_height").html($("#item_height").html() + "<option value="50">50</option>")
```

Or something smarter but it's the idea.

Comment: How do I loop through the data returned from the Ajax call?

Comment: Two options : the returned data is exactly the html code you want to insert (not very flexible but simple) or you loop trough the data. If you want to make this loop your data must be a json array (to_json method). You can use this jquery method : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/.